# Stray threads in Python gstreamer use

Tags: python, multithreading, gstreamer

I have noticed that after I use gstreamer via python (using python-gst-1.0 deb package version 1.2.0-1 from Ubuntu 14.04), I seem to have a stray thread for every encoder run.  I have the gstreamer interface within a module I wrote, and it does the gobject.mainloop within the module, and does mainloop.quit(), so I wouldn't expect that it's the mainloop itself.

After a few runs, threading.enumerate() is showing:

```
[<_MainThread(MainThread, started 140079923849024)>,
 <_DummyThread(Dummy-1, started daemon 140079768815360)>,
 <_DummyThread(Dummy-3, started daemon 140079785338624)>,
 <_DummyThread(Dummy-4, started daemon 140079418832640)>,
 <_DummyThread(Dummy-2, started daemon 140079802386176)>]
```

Thankfully, they are started with daemon, so the program will exit, but I'm at a loss as to how to clean these up.  They are affecting the possibility to use Ctrl-C to exit the script, as the KeyboardInterrupt is not always seeming to come to the MainThread.  I end my run loop with:

```
try:
    time.sleep(899.0)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

time.sleep(1.0)
```

This should allow me to abort the loop timeout by hitting Ctrl-C twice rapidly as the first time catches the try/except, and the second one has no handler on the 1s sleep, and thus quits.  However, with the stray threads, the second Ctrl-C is somehow never seen at this level, so I need to Ctrl-Z to get to the shell and forcefully kill the script.  I don't like it.

Anyone have any idea what this stray thread would be, and how to have it cooperate and die for me?  I'm about to break gdb out on a running process to determine what it might be.

The class code (stripped down to remove irrelevant parts):

```
class GstEncoder:
    def __init__(self, metadata, mediainfo):
        self.error = None

        # used for controlling logic which I removed for clarity
        self.metadata = metadata
        self.mediainfo = mediainfo

        # Create a pipeline in self.pipeline
        self.setupPipeline()

        # Put in the MainLoop
        self.mainloop = GObject.MainLoop()
        self.context = self.mainloop.get_context()
        self.abort = False

    def __del__(self):
        logger.info("Dying gasp!")
        if self.mainloop.is_running():
            self.mainloop.quit()
        self.pipeline.unref()

    def start(self):
        # Set in playing mode
        self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

        # actually only used in some situations, removed the controlling logic for clarity
        GObject.timeout_add_seconds(900, self.timedOut)
        GObject.timeout_add_seconds(30, self.progressReport)

        try:
            self.abort = False
            self.mainloop.run()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            logger.warning("Aborted by Ctrl-C")
            self.abort = True
            self.mainloop.quit()
            raise KeyboardInterrupt

        # Stop the pipeline
        self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
        return self.error

    def progressReport(self):
        position = self.pipeline.query_position(Gst.Format.TIME)[1]
        duration = self.pipeline.query_duration(Gst.Format.TIME)[1]
        if self.abort:
            return False
        percentage = 0.0 if duration == 0 \
                         else float(position) / float(duration) * 100.0
        logger.info("Progress: %s / %s  (%.2f%%)" % (Gst.TIME_ARGS(position),
                Gst.TIME_ARGS(duration), percentage))
        return True

    def timedOut(self):
        if self.abort:
            return False
        self.error = "Aborted by watchdog timer"
        logger.warning(self.error)
        self.abort = True
        self.mainloop.quit()
        return False
```

This is instantiated as:

```
err = None
# Filename, etc is in metadata
encoder = GstEncoder(metadata, mediainfo)
if encoder.error:
    err = encoder.error
if not err:
    err = encoder.start()

if err:
    logger.error(err)

encoder = None
print threading.enumerate()
```

An example pipeline can be seen at:  https://s3.amazonaws.com/beirdo-share/before.png

Comment: I will need some example code to answer, I've been using gstreamer in python a lot and never met that problem. (For example what do you mean 'for every encoder run' ?)

Comment: By every run, I mean every time I instantiate a class that does gstreamer stuff in it.  I'll go update the question shortly with some sample code.  Have you tried doing a "threading.enumerate()" after your mainloop is finished and quit, and you've unrefed your pipeline?

Comment: It's difficult to reproduce without actual working code :) I believe this is an issue with rest of your code / setup. For example, here is a stripped down and working version of your code that doesn't exhibit any issue : http://www.fpaste.org/147332/14979029/

Comment: Lines 22 and 26 are definitely different than my code.  I didn't do a source_remove operation on the timers.  I wonder if it's not my progress timer still running...  Hmmm.   I'll have to experiment with that.

Comment: These lines are just the correct way to remove these timeouts from an existing mainloop, disposing of the mainloop anyway will make this code useless, I just made the class' instances reusable.

Comment: Can't hurt to make it cleaner.  Still, the threads live on.  My next attempt is to wait for the state change of the pipeline to NULL to finish before returning.  It could possibly be a task thread for part of the pipeline.  I have checked with gdb, and all I can tell is that it's part of the glib mainloop-related code, so I'll keep chasing it.  Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into an issue that sounds the same: Ctrl-C triggers a `KeyboardInterrupt` but the process doesn't exit due to non-daemon gstreamer threads. The fix was to call `GObject.threads_init()` once on application startup.